# Is there any way to make the SwiftPackage use only languages supported by the root module?

Tags: swift, xcode, localization, swiftpm

I have a project that supports limited amount of languages. For example:

[image]

I have a Package that supports a wider amount of languages

[image]

Is there any way to make the Package use only languages supported by the root module? The Package uses a system language that is present in the Package but is not supported by the root module. So the app looks not consistent.

Possible solutions

- Add a local Package and remove other languages by hand. But I won't get all the updates from the Package in this case.
- Also, I can make a branch in the Package repo, and specify the branch instead version. But it also won't update automatically.

Comment: Why a package would have localization support is beyond me :roll

Comment: It's possible to move "Universal views" into the package. "Views" contains some text. The text might need to be localized. Sparkle is a good example.